# What is the best way to organise my Wordpress Site content?

Tags: wordpress, categories

Interested to know the best way to use Wordpress for displaying various items where:

- There are several Ranges (Styles) to choose from; then
- Each Range contains several Collections; then
- Each Collection contains several items; and
- Each Item has tags.

My initial thoughts are use Categories for the Collections and Posts for items and each of the posts will contain tags to allow them to be searched. But how should I create the Ranges and place Categories under each Range? Do I assign two Categories and then filter them? or do I create a page for each range and then add a loop of posts to those pages and filter?

What is the best way to achieve this?

By way of an example, what I am trying to achieve could be seen as similar to this fashion example:

Ranges could be different Fashion Designers;
The collection could be Menswear, Womens and kids collections by that Designer;
The items are the individual clothes to buy, each available in different sizes, colours etc.

Thanks

Comment: This could end up very opinion based, I'm debating whether it should really be on here. There's no programming question really... could you maybe try to adapt it, and includ esome code of an issue you're having based on one of your points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me this sounds like a good usage of [custom post types (CPT)](https://codex.wordpress.org/custom_post_type) and [custom taxonomies](https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#Custom_Taxonomies).

Thus you can add a CPT named `clothing_item` and attach certain taxonomies to it such as `designer`, `collection`, `season` and whatever else you can think of.

The advantage of this approach is the fact that you can still keep the default functionality of posts in case you decide to add a blog functionality to your site. Another advantage is that you can enable visualising the items across the different taxonomies. Say you have designers `John A. Doe` and `John B. Doe`. You could, by using taxonomies, see all the items from the `menswear` range of both designers, while if you had a child category called `menswear` for both of the designers you couldn't even if they were the same.

This applies best if you code your own theme. If not, you can still write your own child theme / plugin, or use an [existing plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=add%20taxonomy%20custom%20post%20type) to add this functionality.

Comment: Thanks Moscar, your reply is really helpful. Sounds like a good approach. I'll look into what you have suggested. Thanks.